# error E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout when setting a firebase recyclerview android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

i got an eror in my recyclerview code, this is just a simple code that retrieve a child from uid database but it doesn't show anything and i get this E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout error in my logcat

here's my MainActivity

```
public class ProsesPesananActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference database;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<Status> list;
    StatusAdapter adapter;

    String uid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_proses_pesanan);

        final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        uid = firebaseAuth.getUid();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_proses);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        list = new ArrayList<Status>();

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("PasFoto").child(uid);
        database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Status s = dataSnapshot.getValue(Status.class);
                    list.add(s);
                }
                adapter = new StatusAdapter(ProsesPesananActivity.this,list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Toast.makeText(ProsesPesananActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });



        }

    }
```

here's my Adapter

```
public class StatusAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StatusAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Status> statuses;

    public StatusAdapter (Context c, ArrayList<Status> s){
        context = c;
        statuses = s;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_status,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.shopId.setText(statuses.get(position).getShopId());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return statuses.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        TextView shopId, ukuran, jumlah, total, status;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            shopId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_shopId);
            ukuran = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ukuran);
            jumlah= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDetailJumlah);
            total = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_total);
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see i tried to retrive the data from firebase into my recyclerview using card layout, but i got nothing instead

Comment: where should i write this data ? im sorry, im new in here.

Comment: After this `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));`

Comment: i can't wrote this setOrientation when i wrote it

Comment: why?are you getting error writing setorientation?

Comment: no it's just i can't write it, it just "red".

Comment: what part is red?

Comment: setOrientation part

Answer (score 0):

The error saying *no adapter attached* means just that. It probably caused by `ValueEventListener.onDataChange()` never get called.

Nevertheless, a better practice would be setting the adapter beforehand and notify the adapter of any changes made. Whatever your intention is, make sure that `ValueEventListener.onDataChange()` gets called at least once, or else it might not work the way you originally wanted. In that case, try to study the actual `ValueEventListener` usage.

```java
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /* ... your code ... */
        list = new ArrayList<Status>();
        adapter = StatusAdapter(this, list);
        // Edit: Set adapter to RecyclerView`
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_proses);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("PasFoto").child(uid);
        database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Status s = dataSnapshot.getValue(Status.class);
                    list.add(s);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Toast.makeText(ProsesPesananActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Additionally, [Jetpack Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) is highly recommended in dealing with `RecyclerView` as it can conserve data & memory usage although the implementation steps are a bit not-really-straight-forward, but sure is fun once you get the hang of it.

Comment: it's still said E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout twice

Comment: @Kaine Apologize, missed the `setAdapter()` part. I've added the missing part, please review the code snippet again.

Comment: the s part in StatusAdapter(this,s) cant be called it need to be declared. but when i declared it as an array it need to be make a new StatusAdapter and i got an error that said

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: @Kaine you have to initialize your array list firsthand. Like so, `list = new ArrayList<Status>();` before everything else.

Comment: still the same, the s in status adapter is red in your code

Comment: @Kaine, replace the `s` with `list` instead. You need to adapt it to your code.